# ReactJS & .Net Core app with "silent" local Active Directory Authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asp.net-core, active-directory, single-page-application

I'm creating a company-internal React SPA application with .Net Core 2.2 back-end.

Company uses AD and once user logs in to their Windows workstation they should be able to access this intranet app **without the need to enter username/password for authentication** - application should "pick up" user's windows credentials, **silently** query AD for account details on the background and authenticate/authorize user based on those plus on app's internal permissions/logic.

Now, the problem with React SPA is that it cannot pick up user's Windows Identity or query AD directly without the need for user to enter their credentials (or so I think). I've seen some posts suggesting using JWT, but I could probably use that only after initial authentication.

So my plan is to try this:
[image]

1. Windows-authenticated user types an app url
2. It hits the .Net Core controller
3. Controller picks up user's Windows Identity, silently queries AD server for any add'l info
4. AD server returns user AD details to controller and it packages those into a JWT token or some kind of user details object
5. Controller returns the view as index.html as react SPA along with "packaged" token that goes to React context or Redux store.
6. that is rendered in browser to end-user
7. .. from then onward it functions as normal SPA communicating with server API endpoints.

**Questions:**

- A. Will this work?
- B. Is there a better/more efficient way to implement "silent" internal-AD authentication with React SPA?
- C. Are there any libraries/tools I can use to make this easier?
- D. I've read about Microsoft's MSAL library, but it only seems to work for Azure and
  would still require a Username/Password?

Comment: What you're looking for is called [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth).

Comment: thanks @GabrielLuci, that part is more or less clear to me, I'm more concerned about how to pass user details/token from controller to React app and use it afterwards